# [Raspberry Pi3B+]Can't use Firefox webdriver on Selenium python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 1128, in
>   _execute_prepared_user_code
>       exec(statements, global_vars)
>
> File "/home/pi/Desktop/test1.py", line 3, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>
> File
>   "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
>   line 164, in **init**
>       self.service.start()
>
> File
>   "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 76, in start
>       stdin=PIPE)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in
>   _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
>
> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 1105, in
>   execute_source
>       return self._prepare_hooks_and_execute(bytecode, None, global_vars)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 1120,
>   in _prepare_hooks_and_execute
>       return self._execute_prepared_user_code(statements, expression, global_vars)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 1137,
>   in _execute_prepared_user_code
>       return {"user_exception": self._vm._prepare_user_exception()}
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 993,
>   in _prepare_user_exception
>       "stack": self._export_stack(last_frame),
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 896,
>   in _export_stack
>       locals=self.export_variables(system_frame.f_locals),
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 850,
>   in export_variables
>       result[name] = self.export_value(variables[name], 100)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 840,
>   in export_value
>       rep = repr(value)
>
> File
>   "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 164, in **repr**
>       type(self), self.session_id)
>
> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'session_id'

Answer (score 1):

1. Reinstall selenium with `pip3 install selenium`
2. Download and unzip [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.11.1/geckodriver-v0.11.1-arm7hf.tar.gz), move to /usr/local/bin
3. Install firefox with `sudo apt-get install firefox-esr`